# What is PHPSESSID and why it is not getting in Localhost and can I use this for any encryption Key

Tags: php, session, cookies, encryption

What is PHPSESSID and why it is not getting in Localhost and can I use this for any encryption Key?

I am using my own encryption and decryption function

and I want one common key for each session so can I use PHPSESSID as a key for each session

and if yes then in Local I am not getting this key in request

NOTE: I can not Use session because at this stage I have not set LOGIN to system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get session id then you can get from below code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$sid = session_id();
echo "Session ID returned by session_id(): ".$sid."<br>";
```

It will be identify the unique user.

Answer (score 2):

PHPSESSID is used by php to identify the session with the visitor of the page, it is unique to each visit, a user will get a new PHPSESSID after there sessioncookie expires or is deleted.
Using PHPSESSID as an encryption key is an option but you must keep in mind that a visitor will get a new one once in a while